# indexedDB onupgradeneeded event never finishes

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, indexeddb

In my app a user should be able to dynamically **create and delete objectStores**. Thanks to indexedDB this operations (why in the world) are just allowed in an *onupgradeneeded*.

After an *onupgradedneeded* is triggered indexedDB never finish this request and gc never collects this connection.

There are only problems at creating and deleting stores in an existing db. The *onupdateneeded* at the beginning (create db and create first store) never makes any problems.

I try to close every db connection before I do an upgrade because there is a bug report for Chromium from 2013 where this problem was mentioned where this was suggested (marked as fixed: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=242115).

The fact that I haven't found any actual information about this problem leads me to the assumption that I was doing sth wrong here in my code :)
But then why do some browsers just do their work ?

This is my code for reproducing this error:

#### db.js

```
// Init IndexedDB
var dbversion;
var oStore;
var dbname = "UserName1"; // == Username
initDB();


function initDB() {
    window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB || window.msIndexedDB;
    window.IDBTransaction = window.IDBTransaction || window.webkitIDBTransaction || window.msIDBTransaction;
    window.IDBKeyRange = window.IDBKeyRange || window.webkitIDBKeyRange || window.msIDBKeyRange

    if (!indexedDB) {
       window.alert("Datenbanksupport im Browser fehlt !")
    }else{
        console.log("indexedDB: Supported !");
        // >> first visit ?
        var vCheck = indexedDB.open(dbname);
        vCheck.onerror = errorHandler;
        vCheck.onversionchange = function(ev) {
            vCheck.close();
        };
        vCheck.onsuccess = function(event){
            var db = vCheck.result;
            dbversion = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("dbversion"));
            if (!dbversion){
                // -- maybe
                dbversion = parseInt(db.version);
                if (dbversion <= 1){
                    // -- definitely
                    var needUpgrade = false;
                    db.close();
                    var request = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion+1);
                    request.onerror = errorHandler;
                    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
                        console.log("indexedDB: start upgrade");
                        var nextDB = request.result;
                        if (!nextDB.objectStoreNames.contains('account')) {
                            nextDB.createObjectStore('account', {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
                        }
                        dbversion += 1;
                        localStorage.setItem("dbversion", dbversion);
                        needUpgrade = true;
                        console.log("indexedDB: upgrade finished");
                    }
                    request.onsuccess = function(event){
                        if (needUpgrade) {
                            var objectStore = event.target.result.transaction(['account'], "readwrite").objectStore("account");
                            row = {
                                'id' : 0,
                                'username' : dbname,
                            };
                            objectStore.add(row);
                        }
                        console.log("indexedDB: init");
                    };
                    request.oncomplete = function(event){request.result.close();}
                }else{
                    // -- no
                    localStorage.setItem("dbversion", dbversion);
                    vCheck.oncomplete = console.log("indexedDB: dbversion unknown (not in localStorage)");
                }
            }else{
                // -- no
                console.log("indexedDB: version", dbversion);
                console.log("indexedDB: init");
            }
        }
    }
}

function listStores() {
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
    request.onerror = errorHandler;
    request.onsuccess = function(event){
        var db = request.result;
        var allStores = db.objectStoreNames;
        console.log(allStores);
    }
    request.oncomplete = function(event){request.result.close();}
}

function addStore(storeName) {
    dbversion = localStorage.getItem("dbversion");
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
    request.onerror = errorHandler;
    request.onsuccess = function(event){
        var db = request.result;
        if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains(storeName)) {
            dbversion = parseInt(dbversion) + 1
            localStorage.setItem("dbversion", dbversion);
            db.close()
            var nextRequest = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
            nextRequest.onversionchange = function(ev) {
                nextRequest.close();
            };
            nextRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
                console.log("indexedDB: creating");
                var nextDB = nextRequest.result;
                nextDB.createObjectStore(storeName, {keyPath: "id", autoIncrement: true});
                oStore = storeName;
                console.log("indexedDB:", storeName, "created");
            }
            nextRequest.onerror = errorHandler;
            nextRequest.oncomplete = function(event){nextRequest.result.close();}
        }else{
            oStore = storeName;
            console.log("indexedDB:", storeName, "already exists. Do nothing...");
        }
    }
}

function selectStore(storeName){
    oStore = storeName;
    console.log("indexedDB: globalVar oStore ==", oStore);
}

function addMember(data) {
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
    request.onerror = errorHandler;
    request.onsuccess = function(event){
        var db = request.result;
        var objectStore = db.transaction([oStore], "readwrite").objectStore(oStore);
        row = {
            'id' : Date.now(),
            'name' : {
                'vname' : data['vname'],
                'nname' : data['nname'],
            },
        }
        objectStore.add(row);
        console.log("indexedDB:", row["id"], "inserted");
    }
    request.oncomplete = function(event){request.result.close();}
    return;
}

function deleteStore(storeName) {
    dbversion = localStorage.getItem("dbversion");
    dbversion = parseInt(dbversion) + 1
    localStorage.setItem("dbversion", dbversion);
    var request = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
    request.onerror = errorHandler;
    request.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
        var db = request.result;
        db.deleteObjectStore(storeName);
        console.log("indexedDB:", storeName, "deleted");
    }
    request.oncomplete = function(event){request.result.close();}
}

function errorHandler(event) {
    console.log("indexedDB: operation went wrong:");
    console.log("indexedDB:", event);
    return;
}
```

#### call this order of functions

```
listStores()
addStore('TestStore')
selectStore('TestStore')
addMember({'vname':'John', 'nname':'Doe'})
deleteStore('TestStore')
listStores() // <<<<<<<<<<<< hangs up !
```

## EDIT:

As Joshua turns out the place of closing the connection was wrong. In addition there is one very important fact:

**Before you can delete an objectStore quickly you have to clear it first !**

#### here is the right deleteStore()

```
function deleteStore(storeName) {
    // First: Clear the store
    var request1 = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
    request1.onsuccess = function(event){
        var connection = event.target.result;

        var objectStore = connection.transaction([storeName], "readwrite").objectStore(storeName);
        var result_clear = objectStore.clear();
        result_clear.onerror = errorHandler;
        result_clear.onsuccess = function(event){
            console.log("indexedDB: clearing Store...");
            // Second: Delete the store
            dbversion += 1;
            localStorage.setItem("dbversion", dbversion);
            var request2 = indexedDB.open(dbname, dbversion);
            request2.onsuccess = function(event){
                var connection2 = event.target.result;

                // ---> Garbage Collection
                connection2.onversionchange = function(event) {
                    connection2.close();
                };

            }
            request2.onerror = errorHandler;
            request2.onupgradeneeded = function(event){
                var connection2 = event.target.result;
                connection2.deleteObjectStore(storeName);
                console.log("indexedDB:", storeName, "deleted");
            }
        }

        // ---> Garbage Collection
        connection.onversionchange = function(event) {
            connection.close();
        };

    }
    request1.onerror = errorHandler;
    request1.oncomplete = function(e){
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to listen for the `blocked` even too, maybe that is firing but you interpret it as freezing because you're not listening for it.

Comment: hmmm I'll give it a try tonight. But even a long blocking of the db would be nasty. I wonder if that is a standard behaviour (where nobody complains about) ...

Comment: "blocked" fired against an open request indicates another connection is still open, preventing an upgrade from proceeding. Blocking for a long period of time sounds like you probably have an unclosed connection and the upgrade is waiting on the connection to be garbage collected, which browsers may not do for minutes (or ever).

Also, your vCheck.onversionchange = function(ev) { vCheck.close(); }; line won't work as expected. 'vCheck' is a request, but the "versionchange" event is fired against a connection (the result of the open request), and similarly close() is a method on a connection.

Comment: Also also... why are you replicating the "check the version and upgrade if necessary" logic in script and storing a version on the side in localStorage? If you simply call `open(name, desired_version)` then upgradeneeded will only fire if needed, and most of your code can be deleted.

Comment: @JoshuaBell Yes you're right. The upgradeneeded is waiting for the gc that never comes. But isn't `vCheck` not the dbconnection in this line: `var vCheck = indexedDB.open(dbname);` ? I never know the dbversion on serverside because it has to change every `addStore`/`deleteStore`. So I have to check the client version first (and save it for later). It sounds like you have an idea for a soloution. Could you write an answer on how and where I have to close the dbconnection after an upgrade ? Should I use a global variable for the dbconnection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you're watching for a `versionchange` event fired against the connection, not the open request.

```
var openRequest = indexedDB.open(name, version);
openRequest.onblocked = function(e) {
  // Another connection is open, preventing the upgrade,
  // and it didn't close immediately.
};
openRequest.onerror = function(e) {
  // Open failed - possibly the version is higher than requested.
};
openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  // Check the current version, and upgrade as needed.
  var connection = openRequest.result;
  if (e.oldVersion < 1) {
    // db is new - create v1 schema
  }
  if (e.oldVersion < 2) {
    // upgrade v1 to v2 schema
  }
  if (e.oldVersion < 3) {
    // upgrade v2 to v3, etc
  }
};
openRequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
  var connection = openRequest.result;
  connection.onversionchange = function(e) {
    // Close immediately to allow the upgrade requested by another
    // instance to proceed.
    connection.close();
  };

  // The connection is open - use it for stuff.
};
```

The above also demonstrates the usual pattern for versioning - your code requests a specific version on open, and upgrades older schemas if needed. When your application needs a new store you increase the version number and introduce an additional step into the upgradeneeded handler.

Comment: Thanks for your input ! I accepted your answer because it was the very important 75% of the soloution. I edited my answer to tidy things a bit up. Look at my edit: **I have to clear the store** before it gets deleted quickly. Without clearing it hangs just at this point.... Can't believe how complicated this db implementation is... you saved my week :)

Answer (score 0):

For large numbers of records, deleting an object store (with an index) on Firefox can be very slow (tens of minutes).  See [Deleting an Indexed DB store can be incredibly slow on Firefox](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2024/02/02/deleting-an-indexed-db-store-can-be-incredibly-slow-on-firefox/).

So it was probably working fine, but taking so long you (reasonably) assumed it had failed.